# How do you parallelize DataFrame creation in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Let's say I have a spark job that looks like following:

```
def loadTable1() {
  val table1 = sqlContext.jsonFile(s"s3://textfiledirectory/")
  table1.cache().registerTempTable("table1")
}  

def loadTable2() {
  val table2 = sqlContext.jsonFile(s"s3://testfiledirectory2/")
  table2.cache().registerTempTable("table2")
} 


def loadAllTables() {
  val thread1 = new Thread()
  thread1.loadTable1()

  val thread2 = new Thread()
  thread2.loadTable2()
}

loadAllTables()
```

When I run the program I got an error like **"SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0"**

Comment: can you please share full error stacktrace?

Comment: +1 for full stacktrace, but parallelization of Spark jobs is not a good idea, it may quickly lead to OutOfMemory exceptions on driver or on executors

Comment: If you want to parallelize a spark job, increase spark parallelism. Or run two jobs in parallel.

Comment: @T.Gawęda I beg to differ on _"parallelization of Spark jobs is not a good idea, it may quickly lead to OutOfMemory exceptions on driver or on executors"_ Care to explain?

Comment: @Dima How could _"to parallelize a spark job, increase spark parallelism."_ help here? _"Running two jobs in parallel"_ is the only answer.

Comment: `val thread1 = new Thread(); thread1.loadTable1()` that **won't** compile.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I just assumed _reading_ the data isn't the only thing that job is doing :)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Two queries, in both Optimizer decides to enable broadcast join - data is broadcasted - OOM, because there's too much data. Async RDD actions were more predictable, because you have to do all this stuff by yourself, in Datasets Optimizer can change query